# Display time in timezone input without converting to user's timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display times in many timezones on a web page. The service givess me the times in ISO8601 format with proper offsets:

```
"ScheduleTimes": {
    "ScheduledDepartureTime": "2017-03-14T21:55:00.000-07:00",
    "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2017-03-16T06:50:00.000+11:00"
}
```

Now, when I display this (departure time) time I need to display it as "14MAR 2155" *regardless of where the user is and what to locale and timezone the browser is set.*

Standard Javascript date() converts to browser-local time. Moment.js and its friends (e.g. react-moment) will do timezone conversion, but, I need to know the timezone.

e.g.

```
<Moment format="HHmm">2017-03-14T21:55:00.000-07:00</Moment>
```

Converts that to the hours/min to your local time. I can give it a timezone but I have to fetch the timezone for a given airport code. I have dozens in any one given display, so I don't really want to do that. (I only have the offset, and the airport, and a huge list of arriving and departing flights so I'm not converting them all one by one).

Normally in the operations control centre this isn't an issue for me: the default timezone is *always* UTC. This is outside the OCC and for a different audience that will expect port-local times. It is not expected by the audience that departure/arrival times would be converted to their own timezone if the other "end" of the journey is in a port in a different timezone.

Other than writing a custom class that parses my dates/times specifically, are there any solutions that *don't* try to convert times into the browser's timezone, and don't need to know the display timezone?

UPDATE

Based on the accepted answer below I created a React component that allows me to also use it in other places where I need a different display format:

```
const moment = require('moment');

class LocalTime extends Component {
    formatLocalTime() {
        const t = this.props['value'];
        const f = this.props['format'];
        if (t && f) {
            return moment.utc(t.substring(0, 23)).format(f).toUpperCase();
        } 
        return "";
    }

    render() {
        const formatLocalTime = this.formatLocalTime();
        return (
            <time>{formatLocalTime}</time>
        );
    }
}
```

So this works as follows, with 'value' and 'format' properties, I can display STD and ETD in different formats in the port-local time:

```
<LocalTime value="2017-03-14T21:55:00.000-07:00" format="DDMMM HH:mm"/>
<LocalTime value="2017-03-14T22:05:00.000-07:00" format="HHmm"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and somewhat dirty:

```
const moment = require('moment');

let departure = '2017-03-14T21:55:00.000-07:00';
let arrival   = '2017-03-16T06:50:00.000+11:00';

function format(t) {
  return moment.utc(t.substring(0, 23)).format('DDMMM HH:mm').toUpperCase();
}

console.log('Departure:', format(departure));
console.log('Arrival  :', format(arrival));

// Outputs:
// Departure: 14MAR 21:55
// Arrival  : 16MAR 06:50
```

It strips the timezone offsets from the string, tells Moment to use the remainder as a UTC timestamp (so it doesn't convert to local), and formats it.

Comment: Thanks Robert: I'll see if I can apply this solution. Quick and Dirty can sometimes win the day!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [timezonecomplete](https://github.com/spiritit/timezonecomplete) library. It doesn't seem to auto-apply the client timezone to the format method.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that library over the next couple of weeks.